# How to return back to the tab group in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

i have the following flow of activity in my application,

Main actitvity->tag group(contain three tabs, from second tab going to launch new activity)- >Activity 1 - > Activity2 - > Activity 3 .

When i click finish in activity 3 , all the activity activity 3 , activity 2 , activity 1  need to be finished , bring back me to Tab group(highlighting 2 tab).
   if don`t need to finish activity1 while launching activity2 , i need these three activity alive, while clicking finish button all three activity need to be closed.

If anyone know the solution means help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish Activity 2 and 1 when closing Activity 3 you could start Activity 2 and 3 with a result and if Activity 3 ends the result returned to Activity 2 informs it to finish itself and send Activity 1 the result to also call finish.